# Error: Input grid is not a valid Meshgrid

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a question. So I have a 3D matrix of XxYxZ = 10x5x20. I want to plot this matrix with the help of isosurface. So first I need to create a mesh grid, but here comes the first problem when I say:    `[X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(1:10,1:5,1:20)`    I get a grid of 5x10x20, but I want 10x5x20. Why is this? My idea was to just change the X and Y    `[Y,X,Z] = meshgrid(1:10,1:5,1:20)`    When I try to plot the matrix with the help of this grid:    `isosurface(X,Y,Z,M)`    I get the error "Input grid is not a valid MESHGRID"

What is the problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

You got screwed by matlab, the X-Dimension is the second and the Y-Dimension is the first. Use it as documented:

```
[m,n,p] = size(V)
[X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(1:n,1:m,1:p)
isosurface(X,Y,Z,V)
```

Please notice the swapped order of n and m in the first and second line.