# Error using interp2 in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I have a 2D matrix, F, which I want to interpolate with `interp2`. To understand how this function works, I have been trying to execute the following line:

```
Fq = interp2(X,Z,F,X,Z);
```

where X and Z are the axes of F after being processed with `meshgrid`. I thought Fq was going to be equal to F, as I am trying to interpolate with the same axes X and Z.

However, I have been given this output:

```
Error using griddedInterpolant
The grid vectors do not define a grid of points that match the given values.
```

Why am I getting that error?

For your information, these are the results of running the function `size` on X, Z and F:

```
>> size(X)

ans =

   109    24

>> size(Z)

ans =

   109    24

>> size(F)

ans =

    24   109
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why is `F` not the same size as `x` and `z`? It should be. Transposing it may help, if the data really corresponds to those points.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Oh my God! It works! That is the sort of issue one is not able to find after hours and hours of typing code! I was kind of freaking out! Thanks.

Comment: Matlab uses two different ways to order the dimensions. Most functions use [row,column,...] while some functions use [X,Y,Z]. Unfortunately row corresponds to Y and column to X, which results in the order [Y,X,Z]. At some point you are probably mixing up booth. [A related question demonstrating the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28418095/2732801)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the function says, your data is not the same size (remember, `[109 24]` is not `[24 109]`).

Seeing your data, it looks like you may have 'F' transposed. If that's the case, then

```
Fq = interp2(X,Z,F.',X,Z);
```

will do the job